# How can I do an Android retrofit 2 recyclerview interface?

Tags: java, android

Here is my code.

My adapter:

```java
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.myviewholder> {
    List<ResponseModel> data;

    private final IOtobusSaatleriInterface iOtobusSaatleriInterface;

    public MyAdapter(List<ResponseModel> data, IOtobusSaatleriInterface iOtobusSaatleriInterface) {

        this.data = data;
        this.iOtobusSaatleriInterface = iOtobusSaatleriInterface;
    }
}
```

And my interface:

```java
public interface IOtobusSaatleriInterface {
    void onItemClick(int position);
}
```

This is where I am failing. Here is my failing home fragment page. Where is the problem?
[image: This is my fail and my fail home fragment page. where is the my fail ?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of **this**, write something like ***HomeFragment.this***.

I assume that HomeFragment implements IOtobusSaatleriInterface.